# laravel set schedule for run command in kernel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, kernel, laravel-6

im using laravel 6 and i want to set a schedule to run a command file. i already create command code and jobs. but i still confuse how to set schedule for run it.

I want the schedule to run with condition like this :

1. Run every month on the 10th.
2. Hours run from 7:00 until 14:00
3. Run every minutes

here is my implementation on kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('report:slide')->monthlyOn(10)->everyMinute()->between('7:00', '14:00');
```

but this not work. please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 if (Carbon::now('Europe/Rome')->format('d') === '10' ) { $schedule->command('Asta:Acquista')->between('07:00', '14:00')->everyMinute();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but that code just run 2 times hours. but i want  run from 7:00 until 14:00

Comment: ok try this code   if (Carbon::now('Europe/Rome')->format('d') === '10' ) {
        $schedule->command('Asta:Acquista')->between('07:00', '14:00')->everyMinute();
        }